# How can I provide a HTML template for a Vue.JS 2 component when mounting in a unit test?

Tags: vue.js

I have Vue.JS v2 components that are structured like this:

The component itself appears in a JavaScript file like this:

```js
new Vue({
  data: { message: "Hello world" },
  el: #myComponent
});
```

And a page in ASP.NET MVC loads the script and provides the template:

```html
<script src="myComponent.js"></script>
<div id="myComponent">
  {{message}}
</div>
```

I want to be able to load the html and the javascript during test initialisation but I'm unsure whether it's even possible. Does the [vue-test-utils API](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#mount) allow for this? And I know this would just all work if I went with single-file components and employ a build pipeline but assume that's not an option for the moment.

Comment: Are not! at least you will need pupper or jsdom to do this

Comment: This is not a component but Vue instance. Poor testability is one of the consequences of cutting corners. They shouldn't necessarily be SFC but they have to be components at least. You can write them in vanilla JS without build step. A template is an integral part of a component, it doesn't help the situation keep it separate like you did. Otherwise there won't be much value in testing script part only. In your current situation you likely have to stick to e2e/integration tests